# Issue in reading next document from Lotus Notes View

Tags: .net, lotus-notes

I have written a .net code to do some operations with documents in lotus notes view. It worked fine for one document, While reading next entry it throws this error highlighting the GetNextDocument line.

```
 Entry not found in index
```

Part of code:

```
doc = view.GetFirstDocument();
While(doc != null)
{
..........
doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc);
}
```

Please suggest whether is there any alternative to do this, or ways to resolve this error. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`doc` gets probably removed from view withing the while loop.

Add

```
view.setAutoUpdate(false)
```

in front of the while loop [see](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.0/appdev/builds/H_AUTOUPDATE_PROPERTY_JAVA.html?hl=autoupdate%2Cproperty).